# Family science fiction movie where aliens chew gumballs to turn into monsters

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

What is the scifi family movie where aliens(?) have these gumballs that whomever chews it turns into an alien/monster/creature thing.

The government is trying to capture the aliens for study and a family is trying to help them escape.

I vividly remember a scene towards the end that the mom chews a gumball that turns her into a big kraken type of monster. It has to be from the 90s, maybe 80s.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Do you mean "family movie" as in "movie about a family", or "movie suitable for viewing by younger family members"?

Comment: So they're aliens that might turn into other aliens?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [*My Favorite Martian*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Favorite_Martian_(film)) (1999).

> At the lab, Tim tricks one of the scientists into growing Martin's
>   ship to normal size, breaching security, and allowing Lizzie and Zoot
>   to escape. However, the trio's escape is blocked by two security
>   guards, one of whom shoots Zoot. With the help of a "nerplex", **a piece
>   of alien gum that can transform anyone into another life form**, Lizzie
>   transforms into a hideous monster from "Veenox 7". She defeats them,
>   then spits out the nerplex and turns back into a human.

Comment: Yes this is the movie thank you so much you have made my day!!!!!!!!!!!!!!